# SuperUser Dialog keep Showing even if i Check 'Remember My Choice'

Tags: java, android, root

In my apps, I request root privileges, I accept it and check 'Remember my Choice', but every times I try to run a command as root, the 'Allow/Disallow' Dialog appears again.

Is there any solution?